# What inits appendChild's script (src in iframe) in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, appendchild

I'd like to understand one thing about JS workflow in a browser. 
Document is a global object. If one adds a new node to the DOM tree (after Document has been loaded and an event took place):

```
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = "https://script.js&param=1"; 
        container.appendChild("iframe");
```

The document starts executing this new node at once, on the go. Why? What in the document inits the script of a new added node?

Comment: Do you mean execution of the script in the new document or something else?

Comment: I mean a document exists, but a new element is being added and this element's script executes as if it was there from the begining, on the page's load. It became to exist and executes at once. It is a browser's behaviour by default. So I'd like understand this inner browser's workflow. Something in browser's code inits it.

Comment: `container.appendChild("iframe");` — I don't think you want whose quotes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing "in the document" triggers the iframe.

The browser is rendering the document.

You are changing the document with JavaScript.

The browser re-renders the document in response.